# Is it possible to set a map to a fraction ratio? (1/2 : 1)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Unlike most people, I want to create a map smaller than the average. I have a minigame on a server that needs a map. Is it possible to set a map to a fraction?  Most maps are 128x128, I would like a 64*64 map, or a 32*32 map, or even a 48*48 map. Could it be done with commands, nbt editing or a plugin? (I would be able to code the plugin myself, I just need to know whether or not it would be executable)

Comment: You might be able to create a command block that kills or ports everyone who leaves the game area. I don't know how to do something like that though.

Comment: @Nzall I think he means the map item.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this impossible. There are only fixed sizes for maps, the smallest being the default.

Comment: You could make every pixel four blocks on the map, which gives the illusion of a 64X64 map on a 128X128 map. Other than that I think it's impossible.